# $\oplus P$ status in polynomial hierarchy

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, big-picture, np, polynomial-hierarchy

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_P) it is stated that it is not known if $\mathsf{P^{\oplus P} \mathrel{(=} \oplus P)}$ contains $\mathsf{NP}$, although it is known that $\mathsf{BPP^{\oplus P}}$ contains $\mathsf{PH}$.

**Questions**

1. Is $\mathsf{\oplus P}$ expected to be contained in $\mathsf{PH}$? If so, at what level might it plausibly be?
2. Is there an analog of $\mathsf{\oplus P}$ in the diophantine hierarchy?

Comment: 1. Nowhere, of course. $\oplus P$ is not in PH at all unless PH collapses, by the $PH\subseteq BPP^{\oplus P}$ result you quote. Your claim that $PH\subseteq BPP^{NP}$ is nonsense. As for 2, it's totally unclear what kind of analogue you mean.

Comment: What kind of diophantine hierarchy do you mean? This one? http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10958-012-1106-7

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind about ${\bf BBP} ^{\bf NP}$ is that ${\bf NP}^{\bf BPP} \subseteq {\bf BPP}^{\bf NP}$. [Zachos and Furer, Probabilistic Quantifier vs distrustful adversaries. 1987]